# Problems launching Blender's Python version on a Mac

Tags: python, macos, blender

I'm having problems launching Blender's version of Python on a Mac. On Windows or Linux, if I download the Blender .zip package, I can navigate into the subdirectory containing the Python binary/executable file and run e.g. "./python3.exe", and it opens a Python interpreter as expected. However when I do the equivalent on a Mac ("./python3.5m") it simply says "killed". Adding the -v switch makes no difference.

Some more details : I'm trying to run an older version of Blender (2.79) which for a host of reasons I cannot avoid using. As a sanity check, doing the same procedure but using Blender 4.1 correctly opens the Python interpreter. Additionally, running Blender (2.79)'s Python in the background to execute a script (e.g. "blender --background --python myscript.py") correctly executes the script. Likewise, Blender itself opens without problems and I can access the internal interpreter and run commands there without issue. It's only when trying to run Python externally via ./python3.5m that I run into problems.

I'm not at all familiar with Macs (working with a Mac-using colleague to try and get a script running), so I really have no clue where to start diagnosing this. It's OS 11.7.9.